# Как сохранить символы пробела при добавлении в базу?

Tags: mysql, php, javascript, textarea, форма

Имеется форма с текстовым полем. В поле возможно добавление пробелов и отступов:

```
В парке гуляла пара.
Они были прекрасны.
.....(пустота - отступы)
.....
Когда к ним подъехала карета
(пробел) Они стремительно...
```

Как сделать, чтобы в БД добавлялась информация с таким минимальным форматированием?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из `textarea` все отступы и пробелы нормально сохраняются в базу без особых манипуляций, я так понял у вас проблема с выводом на страницу, решение лежит на поверхности - в HTML, используйте у нужного блока `white-space: pre;` и всё будет выводиться как нужно. [Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/13nmyvw9/)

Comment: Поставил бы Вам 100 плюсов.